# проблема с добавлением SSH ключа в github

Tags: git, github, git-push

GitHub обновили протокол безопасности, и поэтому мне пришлось переделывать мой SSH ключ, но после того, как я переделал мой SSH ключ как предлагал GitHub у меня вылезает такая ошибка:

```
 /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: IgnoreUnknown
/Users/nimaymac/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: AddKeysToAgent
/Users/nimaymac/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: UseKeychain
/Users/nimaymac/.ssh/config: terminating, 3 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Я пробовал убирать строчки, которые ему не нравились, но это приводило к этому:

```
ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.
Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Можно ли это как то починить? Заранее спасибо!
система: macos 10.10.5

---

как я переделывал ключ:

1. ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
2. eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
3. open /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/config
   4)записал в файл /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/config:
   Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/id_rsa
4. ssh-add -K /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/id_rsa
   Такая инструкция была дана на гитхабе

Comment: Создавайте себе ключ ed25519, а не rsa

Comment: Что-то я не понял при чём тут .ssh/config

Comment: И опишите как именно вы «переделывали ключ»?

Comment: @AlexeyTen 
1) `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
2) `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
3) `open ~/.ssh/config`
4) `Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/id_rsa`
5) `ssh-add -K /Users/nimaymac/.ssh/id_rsa`
Такая инструкция была дана на гитхабе

Comment: @AlexeyTen "чтобы автоматически загружать ключи в ssh-agent и сохранять парольные фразы в вашей цепочке ключей." так написано на гитхабе

Comment: @user7860670 при вводе `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"` пишет: `unknown key type ed25519`; гитхаб в таком случае советует использовать `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Comment: ¿А у вас ssh актуальной версии? Обновите. Гитхаб уже перевел rsa в раздел legacy.

Comment: Эм, опция IgnoreUnknown появилась в OpenSSH в 2013 году. У вас ssh старше что ли? Или он не openssh на маке? Что пишет `ssh -V`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen оооо так вот в чем дело... у меня старинная версия OpenSHH 2011 года. Я насколько понимаю mac os придется более новую ставить?